# .NET app service need SDK to run on Linux?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, api, nginx

We are trying to run the .net core API service on Cent OS using Nginx server. Do we need .NET SDK or run time libraries are enough to run the .NET service on Linux?

Comment: Runtime libraries are enough.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. If you have a self-contained application, you dont even need the .NET runtime. If you have a framework-dependent application, you will need the runtime installed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: @omajid - Thank you for the clarification. I found all the details that I'm looking for in that link. Please check if you can provide this as an answer, would like to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are publishing the application.

If your application is published as a Framework Dependent application, it will need just the .NET Runtime to be installed.

If your application is published as a Self-Contained application, it will not need the .NET Runtime to be installed (but the transitive native dependencies of .NET runtime - such as OpenSSL and ICU might be needed).

At no point should the SDK be required to run the application. If it is, you are doing something wrong, or have run into a bug.

For more details, see:

- [.NET Application Publishing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)
- [Publishing .NET applications with the .NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).

If you are targeting Linux running Intel x86_64 machines, remember to use [the `linux-x64` Runtime Identifier when targeting the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).